# How to concatenate the values that have a "." in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql-9.1

I have this table

1.3.6.7.8

 22.6.99.9

 1-3-6-7-9

 1 3 6 7 9

After my request postgresql I want this

13678

 226999

 13679

 13679

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This looks like simple string replacement

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b7718b608483f789e9787dd32c6c8c7) is a db<>fiddle.